# Matrix Subgroups of $SO(2,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

What subgroups of $SO(2,\mathbb{R})$ are isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, and what subgroups of $O(n,\mathbb{R})$ are isomorphic to $S_n$)?

Comment: You want only one example, or you want to satisfy them?

Comment: Only an example I think would be good.

Answer (score 0):

There are two examples.

For the first case, consider element of the form $I + A_t$, where $A_t$ is the matrix with $t$ in the (1, 2) entry and zero otherwise.

For the second case, consider permutations as matrices. They are all in $O(n, \mathbb R)$.